# Consecutive queries in same connection not working

Tags: php

The following code is working just fine, but the line `$connection->query('call user_create(145552, \'a@a.com\');');` is not creating a user into the database.

```
function updateFacebook($id) {

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'databasename');
    $count = $connection->query('call user_by_facebook_read(' . $id . ');')->num_rows;

    if ($count == 0) {

        $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
        $body = $request->getBody();
        $json = json_decode($body);
        $token = $json->token;

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => 'value',
            'secret' => 'value',
            'cookie' => true
        ));

        $facebook->setAccessToken($token);

        $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
            'message' => 'message',
            'picture' => 'https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo4w.png',
            'link' => 'https://www.google.com.br',
            'description' => 'description',
            'name' => 'name',
            'caption'=> 'caption'
        ));

        $connection->query('call user_create(145552, \'a@a.com\');');

    }

    $connection->close;

    $json = json_encode(array(
        'r' => true
    ));

    echo $json;     

}
```

If I run the following code it also works just fine:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'databasename');
$connection->query('call user_create(145552, \'a@a.com\');');
$connection->close;
```

If I close the connection after the `$count` and open it again before the user_create call it also works.

What is happening?

Comment: Do you know if the query is actually being run? In other words, are you sure you're even getting to that line of code?

Comment: Yeh. I'm sure. Take a look in my edit.

Comment: You need to run `->close()` on the result, but you discarded that. So: `$result = $connection->query(..); $count = $result->num_rows;$result->close();`.

Comment: If after that you _still_ have an error, [look at this comment in the docs](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904)

Comment: @Wrikken my bad, calling `$result->close()` and `$connection->next_result();` works. Please post it as a answer.

Comment: Hah, I like this _"testing whether an answer is correct before actually committing to it myself"_ :P Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `->close()` on the result, but you discarded that. So:

```
 $result = $connection->query(..);
 $count = $result->num_rows;
 $result->close();
```

[and after CALL()s in MySQLi it seems to need this:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904)

```
 $connection->next_result();
```